# Retrieve an object from a random array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, I would like the click to retrieve a different a random object. I tried as below but it doesn't work. Thank you for help

I modified the post, I added the complete component so that you can see my problem

```
const data = [
{  
  firstname: "john",
  lastname: "john"
},
{  
  firstname: "peter",
  lastname: "peter"
}];

const RandomCollaborator = () => {
        
  const test = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)]
  console.log(test)

  return test;      
}
```

error console : NaN

```
const AccountComponent = () => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    getListCollaboratorService(dispatch);
    const [ errorListCollaborater, setErrorListCollaborater ] = useState(null);
    const storageUserDetails = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
    const [listCollaborater, setListCollaborater] = useState("");
    const userDetails= JSON.parse(storageUserDetails);
    const storeListCollaborater = userDetails === null ? useSelector(state => state.reducerListCollaborater.state) : userDetails

   
   useEffect(()=> {
        setListCollaborater(localStorage.getItem("listCollaborater"))
       
   }, [listCollaborater])
    
   const test1  = listCollaborater
    const RandomCollaborater = () => {
 
        const test = Math.floor(Math.random() * test1.length)
        
        return test;
        
    }
    
   
    return(
        <div>
            <div>

            <RandomCollaborater />
        </div>
    )
}


export default AccountComponent;
```

Comment: Your code works for me; I do not get `NaN`. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Also, it's *collaborator*, not *collaborater*.

Comment: Declare `const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);` then `console.log(index);` to see the value it gets.

Comment: I've just run your code into the chrome devTools and it works just fine. If there's something wrong in your code, it comes from somewhere else. Show us your entire component.

Comment: I receive the number of letters, I cannot retrieve an entire object

Comment: I modified the post, I added the complete component @FlorentArlandis

Comment: If you store it in local storage you need to parse the json when retrieving the data.

Comment: Thank you, but how to recover the object with the index which I have to recover @kennarddh